# Extjs: Cannot read property 'substring' of undefined

Tags: javascript, extjs

hi i want add grid panel to my view in Extjs 4.1.1 , but i get this error in browser console "Cannot read property 'substring' of undefined" . This is my js code:

```
Ext.require([
                  '*'
              ]);
     Ext.onReady(function(){

            Ext.tip.QuickTipManager.init();
            Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                storeId:'simpsonsStore',
                fields:['name', 'email', 'phone'],
                data:{'items':[
                    { 'name': 'Lisa',  "email":"lisa@simpsons.com",  "phone":"555-111-1224"  },
                    { 'name': 'Bart',  "email":"bart@simpsons.com",  "phone":"555-222-1234" },
                    { 'name': 'Homer', "email":"home@simpsons.com",  "phone":"555-222-1244"  },
                    { 'name': 'Marge', "email":"marge@simpsons.com", "phone":"555-222-1254"  }
                ]},
                proxy: {
                    type: 'memory',
                    reader: {
                        type: 'json',
                        root: 'items'
                    }
                }
            });

            Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
                title: 'Simpsons',
                store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('simpsonsStore'),
                columns: [
                    { text: 'Name',  dataIndex: 'name' },
                    { text: 'Email', dataIndex: 'email', flex: 1 },
                    { text: 'Phone', dataIndex: 'phone' }
                ],
                height: 200,
                width: 400,
                renderTo:  Ext.Element.get('test')
            });

        });
```

and this is html code :

```
   <div id="test"> </div>
```

Comment: sorry can you please paste the console text? how can i find what is undefined?

Comment: You are using the `substring()` function on a variable that you expect to contain a string, but which isn't a string. The stack trace (which chrome provides in console by default, just click the gray triangle...) would be really helpful.

Comment: this is a snapshot of error :http://prntscr.com/a4dc7m

Comment: same code is working for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to get an element by ID is: `Ext.get("my-div");`
http://www.objis.com/formationextjs/lib/extjs-4.0.0/docs/api/Ext.core.Element.html

So I believe you need to change `renderTo: Ext.Element.get('test')` to: `renderTo: Ext.get('test')`